# how to perform left outer join in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, join, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes a and b:

a has following columns:

```
t_id
s_id
first_name
last_name
country_name
```

b has following columns:

```
t_id
s_id
first_name
last_name
```

I have to do a left outer join to get the records in a but want to use first_name and last_name from dataframe b instead of first_name and last_name from a dataframe and store the results in finaloutput. I want the column names to remain as is.

I have used the below dataframe query:

please could you advise.

```
finaloutput = a.merge(right=b[["first_name","last_name"]], on = ["t_id","s_id"], how = "left")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) same column in `a`:

```
finaloutput=a.drop(['first_name','last_name'],axis=1).merge(b,on=["t_id","s_id"],how="left")
```

Another solution - parameter `on` can be omit if `a` and `b` have same column for join:

```
finaloutput = a[['t_id','s_id','country_name']].merge(b, how = "left")
```

More dynamic solution is find all columns for selecting by [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
lcols = a.columns.difference(b.columns).tolist()
joincols = ["t_id","s_id"]
finaloutput = a[lcols + joincols].merge(b, how = "left")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
finaloutput = a[['t_id','s_id','country_name']].merge(b,on=["t_id","s_id"], how = "left")
```

this work